# Calendar text label will not Update

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(datePicker:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    dateFormat()

} //this works
func dateFormat() {
    let today = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let short = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = short
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-YYYY"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    dateLbl.text = startDate

    //this works but datePicker date when moved will not update
    let thirtyDays = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day,value: 30, to: today as Date)
    let tomorrowSixty = dateFormatter.string(from: thirtyDays!)
    sixtyDay.text = tomorrowSixty

}
func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker){
    dateFormat()

}

}
```

Comment: Where is dateLbl coming from?

Comment: dateLbl is the Outlet:
    IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
    
    IBOutlet weak var sixtyDay: UILabel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3 it is batter if you use `Date` and `Calendar` instead of `NSDate` and `NSCalendar`.

Now if you want to set the `sixtyDay` label with the date after the 30 days of datePicker date then you need to use `datePicker.date` with `date(byAdding:)` instead of today date.

```
func dateFormat() {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    dateLbl.text = startDate

    //this works but datePicker date when moved will not update
    let thirtyDays = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: datePicker.date)
    let tomorrowSixty = dateFormatter.string(from: thirtyDays!)
    sixtyDay.text = tomorrowSixty
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker){
    dateFormat()
}
```

**Note:** If you are setting `dateFormat` with `DateFormatter` then no need to set `dateStyle` with `DateFormatter` also the correct year formatter is `yyyy` not `YYYY`.

Comment: the sixtyDay.text on the build does not update if the datepicker dial is moved...the date does change on dateLbl.text but not on the sixtyday.text, it stays the same current day

Comment: @rpbones531 Check the edited answer change the line `let thirtyDays = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: datePicker.date)`

Comment: @rpbones531 Welcome mate :)